# Configure ssh-agent for TeamCity agent

Tags: centos, ssh, ssh-agent, teamcity

I have TeamCity agents installed on a CentOS 7.3 server, and am trying to use the "SSH agent" build feature for a script that uses `scp`.
However, it always fails due to a TimeoutException:

```
[12:39:32]  [Step 1/4] Failed to load SSH key 'Staging & Deployment Key_'
[12:39:31]  [Step 1/4] 'ssh-add /home/agent/002/temp/buildTmp/teamcity979243148311152591sshKey' command failed
exception: jetbrains.buildServer.ProcessTimeoutException: Timeout exception: the process did not produce output longer than 5 seconds; Process: ssh-add /home/agent/002/temp/buildTmp/teamcity979243148311152591sshKey
exit code: -1
[12:39:31]  [Step 1/4] Starting: /home/agent/002/temp/agentTmp/custom_script5200058812461913901
[12:39:31]  [Step 1/4] in directory: /home/agent/002/work/7facf668c0fd7484
[12:39:32]  [Step 1/4] Process exited with code 0
[12:39:32]  [Step 1/4] Step Create local directories (Command Line) failed
```

Can anyone tell me whether this is an SSH issue, and agent setup issue, or a build configuration issue?
[TeamCity docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/ssh-agent.html) claim this should work out of the box, so they're not much help on troubleshooting this.